# Passing Dictionary as an argument in Helm Template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I wonder if there is anyway for us to pass dictionary as an argument in Helm Templates. In Python, I could simply create some scripts like this but I am not sure how to translate this script into Helm.

```
>>> def display(d):
...     for key in d:
...             print("key:", key, "Value:", d[key])
... 
>>> def func():
...     D = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
...     display(D)
... 
>>> func()
key: a Value: 1
key: b Value: 2
key: c Value: 3
```

I tried to implement some script like this but they seem does not solve out.

_helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "display"}}
{{- $d := .d -}}
{{- range $key, $value := $d -}}
  {{- printf "%s-%s" $key $value-}}
{{- end -}}
```

_test.tpl

```
{{- define "func"}}
{{- $D = dict 'a' 1 'b' 2 'c' 3} -}}
{{- $res := include "display" (dict "d" $D) -}}
{{- $res -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Would you give me some working examples of how a dictionary is passed as an arguments in helm?
Thank you in advance for your help! I am much appreciate it!

Comment: I've written up an answer to the questions you're asking, but my sample code looks very similar to yours (you need to make sure to use double quotes in `_test.tpl` when you define the variable `$D`).  Is there a more specific error or problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 3):

A Go `text/template` template takes only one parameter.  It has the special name `.` inside the template.  That parameter can be any type, though, and in a Helm context there are extension functions like [`list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) and [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) that can assemble the containers.

A template can only *return* a string, and if you need to capture that return value then you need to use the Helm [`include`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) extension function rather than the standard template `template` directive.  Anything the template outputs is part of that "return value" and there is not a specific "return" command.

So, for example, your `display` function is pretty easy to write: its one parameter is a dictionary and you use a `range` loop to iterate over its contents.  (I'm dumping it out as a YAML list, which would be a more typical Kubernetes/Helm output.)

```yaml
{{- define "display" -}}
{{- range $k, $v := . -}}
- key: {{ $k }}
  value: {{ $v }}
{{ end -}}
{{ end -}}
```

And then to call it, you'd construct a dictionary with `dict` (or extract one from `.Values`) and pass that dictionary to the function.

```yaml
{{- $d := dict "a" 1 "b" 2 "c" 3 }}
{{- include "display" $d -}}
```